# Is there proper way to train a model with forms without table borders?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

When I upload a document for form recognition the results I'm getting don't seem to align with the structure of the document. It seems very hit or miss. In my example there is a grid with product descriptions, qty, part number, and price. Only the first row in the description is correlated with the qty, price, and part number. The remaining rows of the description are found in other places of the response without correlation to the first row.

Here's a sample of the quote layout

[image]

I have upload complete documents and a blank form, both simple and complex with multiple pages. And this is part of the result with the missing data.

```
{   
    "header": [
        {
            "text": "ITEM",
            "boundingBox": [
                43.8,
                527.5,
                65.4,
                527.5,
                65.4,
                519.7,
                43.8,
                519.7
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entries": [
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.7,
                    512.1,
                    278.7,
                    512.1,
                    278.7,
                    504.3,
                    43.7,
                    504.3
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.7,
                    438.7,
                    278.7,
                    438.7,
                    278.7,
                    430.9,
                    43.7,
                    430.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.7,
                    357.7,
                    278.7,
                    357.7,
                    278.7,
                    349.9,
                    43.7,
                    349.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.7,
                    276.4,
                    278.7,
                    276.4,
                    278.7,
                    268.7,
                    43.7,
                    268.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.7,
                    195.4,
                    278.7,
                    195.4,
                    278.7,
                    187.7,
                    43.7,
                    187.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "F5 BIG-IP Service Premium (Level 1-3) - technical support",
                "boundingBox": [
                    43.8,
                    114.5,
                    278.8,
                    114.5,
                    278.8,
                    106.8,
                    43.8,
                    106.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "header": [
        {
            "text": "QTY",
            "boundingBox": [
                304.9,
                527.5,
                320.6,
                527.5,
                320.6,
                519.7,
                304.9,
                519.7
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entries": [
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    512.8,
                    315.1,
                    512.8,
                    315.1,
                    504.3,
                    310.7,
                    504.3
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    439.3,
                    315.1,
                    439.3,
                    315.1,
                    430.9,
                    310.7,
                    430.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    358.3,
                    315.1,
                    358.3,
                    315.1,
                    349.9,
                    310.7,
                    349.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    277.1,
                    315.1,
                    277.1,
                    315.1,
                    268.7,
                    310.7,
                    268.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    196.1,
                    315.1,
                    196.1,
                    315.1,
                    187.7,
                    310.7,
                    187.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "1",
                "boundingBox": [
                    310.7,
                    115.2,
                    315.1,
                    115.2,
                    315.1,
                    106.8,
                    310.7,
                    106.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "header": [
        {
            "text": "Part#",
            "boundingBox": [
                356.2,
                527.5,
                381.9,
                527.5,
                381.9,
                519.7,
                356.2,
                519.7
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entries": [
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    512.8,
                    384.6,
                    512.8,
                    384.6,
                    504.3,
                    353.6,
                    504.3
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    439.3,
                    384.6,
                    439.3,
                    384.6,
                    430.9,
                    353.6,
                    430.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    358.3,
                    384.6,
                    358.3,
                    384.6,
                    349.9,
                    353.6,
                    349.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    277.1,
                    384.6,
                    277.1,
                    384.6,
                    268.7,
                    353.6,
                    268.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    196.1,
                    384.6,
                    196.1,
                    384.6,
                    187.7,
                    353.6,
                    187.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "3158598",
                "boundingBox": [
                    353.6,
                    115.2,
                    384.6,
                    115.2,
                    384.6,
                    106.8,
                    353.6,
                    106.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "header": [
        {
            "text": "UNIT PRICE",
            "boundingBox": [
                431.0,
                527.5,
                480.5,
                527.5,
                480.5,
                519.7,
                431.0,
                519.7
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entries": [
        [
            {
                "text": "$10,003.53",
                "boundingBox": [
                    439.7,
                    512.8,
                    480.1,
                    512.8,
                    480.1,
                    504.3,
                    439.7,
                    504.3
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$30,815.03",
                "boundingBox": [
                    439.7,
                    439.3,
                    480.1,
                    439.3,
                    480.1,
                    430.9,
                    439.7,
                    430.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$6,401.54",
                "boundingBox": [
                    444.2,
                    358.3,
                    480.3,
                    358.3,
                    480.3,
                    349.9,
                    444.2,
                    349.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$10,003.53",
                "boundingBox": [
                    439.7,
                    277.1,
                    480.1,
                    277.1,
                    480.1,
                    268.7,
                    439.7,
                    268.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$16,006.85",
                "boundingBox": [
                    439.7,
                    196.1,
                    480.1,
                    196.1,
                    480.1,
                    187.7,
                    439.7,
                    187.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$2,399.33",
                "boundingBox": [
                    444.2,
                    115.2,
                    480.3,
                    115.2,
                    480.3,
                    106.8,
                    444.2,
                    106.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "header": [
        {
            "text": "EXT. PRICE",
            "boundingBox": [
                513.7,
                527.5,
                558.2,
                527.5,
                558.2,
                519.7,
                513.7,
                519.7
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entries": [
        [
            {
                "text": "$10,003.53",
                "boundingBox": [
                    517.8,
                    512.8,
                    558.3,
                    512.8,
                    558.3,
                    504.3,
                    517.8,
                    504.3
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$30,815.03",
                "boundingBox": [
                    517.8,
                    439.3,
                    558.3,
                    439.3,
                    558.3,
                    430.9,
                    517.8,
                    430.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$6,401.54",
                "boundingBox": [
                    522.4,
                    358.3,
                    558.4,
                    358.3,
                    558.4,
                    349.9,
                    522.4,
                    349.9
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$10,003.53",
                "boundingBox": [
                    517.8,
                    277.1,
                    558.3,
                    277.1,
                    558.3,
                    268.7,
                    517.8,
                    268.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$16,006.85",
                "boundingBox": [
                    517.8,
                    196.1,
                    558.3,
                    196.1,
                    558.3,
                    187.7,
                    517.8,
                    187.7
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "text": "$2,399.33",
                "boundingBox": [
                    522.4,
                    115.2,
                    558.4,
                    115.2,
                    558.4,
                    106.8,
                    522.4,
                    106.8
                ],
                "confidence": 1.0
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form Recognizer V2 has hit public preview recently. It supports train with label feature now, you can try to label some sample forms before training the model. In this way, you have more control over what data from the form is interesting to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/overview